# Attach picture to Facebook for Android Share Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am currently trying out the Facebook for Android Share Dialog(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/) that was introduced in Facebook for Android SDK 3.5.

The code for starting the dialog is straight forward:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
     .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
     .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Similar to setLink() there is a setPicture(String url) method in FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder. But I can't get this setPicture() method to work. I have tried to put Url to local image files, online images and also FB staged images (fbstage://...) but nothing seems to make any effect on the Share Dialog viewed or the resulting post.

Is there anyone that got the setPicture() method to work?

Comment: Do you see the post on facebook, but without the image or the post isn't shown at all?

Comment: have you got it done, i have the same issue with local file

Comment: @sromku: I see the post but without image.

Comment: @Jacky: No, no progress yet. Have you managed to attach any picture at all?

Comment: @semmelway see my answer below

Comment: @semmelway i can use an internet URL(it works), but not a local URL.

Comment: The picture parameter must be a url, not a uri (i.e. it must be reachable via the internet).

Answer (score 1):

from documentation of [facebook feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

```
The picture must be at least 200px by 200px.
```

And even more restriction on image to be, check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#tags)

`This is an image associated with your media. We suggest that you use an image of at least 200x200 pixels. However, bigger is better, so if you have a 1500x1500 image that you can use, please use it. We'll downsample and crop it for for people using smaller-resolution devices but will use it on a larger device. The larger this image is, the more likely it will be used when sharing stories on Facebook. (Note: image sizes must be no more than 5MB in size.)`

Comment: Thanks. But you are talking about Open Graph stories. I want to do a plain status update and providing an image. Then there is no algorithms deciding to show the image or not.

Comment: i just need to confirm whether a local image(like:file:///data/data/com.xb.android_3/cache/Images/default_pack_cover_image.jpg)  is supported or not?

Comment: @Jacky, nope, it must be a valid url with http or https. like: http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg

Comment: @semmelway the first comment relates to feed images url. they should be at minimum 200x200, and point to a valid url. the second comment indeed relates to stories, but i think that the same algorithm approach works for both feeds and stories in term of images.

Answer (score 1):

With `ShareDialogBuilder` its not permitted to shared a local file but only remote files.

Currently I think that the only way (via a share dialog) is through the open graph action dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to call the setPicture() should be used with setLink().

Please refer to the article below.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder/

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an external URL like:

.setPicture("http://yourdomain.com/images/xyz.png");

Also, it will only display if you've set the link.